# Media queries only work in responsive mode of multiple browsers

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, bootstrap-4

I've built my website using Bootstrap 4. There were some issues with the responsive design so I used media queries to fix those issues. The whole time I'm using Chrome's device toolbar to make the changes to the CSS. While using the device toolbar everything looks as I want it to but when I resize the browser outside of the device toolbar the media queries no longer work. I've tried this in both Chrome and Firefox.

I've prematurely made my site live to see if the issue would still persists when live and the issue is still there. Has anyone encountered this before?

[Lakhan Production](http://www.lakhaniproductions.com) is the URL. I would greatly appreciate any feedback and insight. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I checked your site on my copy of Firefox (57.0 64-bit) and it seems to be working.  Is there a specific CSS rule you are expecting that isn't working?

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to look into this. If you resize the browser to 400px, you'll see that the toggler is not where it's supposed to be. That's just one example. 

If you go into the device toolbar you'll see what it's actually supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your media queries, you used `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`:  The *device width*  measures the device (phone, tablet etc.), not the browser window. That's the reason for what you describe. The mobile developer mode of Chrome apparently also emulates the devices that way.

I would rather use `min-width` and `max-width` instead of `min-device-width` and `max-device-width`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that but why would the media queries work as they are now in the device toolbar and not in the actual browser? Do you think if I change it to min-width/max-width the issue will no longer exist?

Comment: because the device toolbar apparently emulates a smaller device, whereas your *device* (i.e. the desktop screen) stays the same size if you just change the window size.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very, very, very much.